# How do I link a shell script to the login / logout event on a Mac so that it triggers when a user logs on / off?

Tags: mac, shell, launchctl

I have been trying to get a shell script to fire on login / logout events on a Mac, but the method I used is very old, and it does not work. I followed this StackExchange post and used the

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook <login script filepath>
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook <logout script filepath>
```

command it describes. However, I learned that this hook is deprecated.

There is some good information in that post about "launchd", and I learned that "launchctrl" might be the modern way of doing what I want to do. However, most of the StackExchange posts I'm finding on this subject are quite outdated.

Could someone please explain in very simple terms which command I need to be using to attach these shell scripts to the login / logout events on a modern Mac using OS X 12+?

For some context, I've already confirmed that the shell scripts themselves work perfectly when launched manually. I now just need them to launch on login and logout. It is my responsibility to develop the documentation for this process, and I've already developed it successfully for PC, but I have no access to a Mac and haven't used one since the late 90s so I'm working remotely with a colleague who owns a Mac (but doesn't know the terminal / commands) to get this document fleshed out.